# div overlapping tooltip when data-position is set to right

Tags: overlap, intro.js

I'm trying to set up intro.js, but I'm having a problem when I try to set the data-position of a tooltip to "right." When I do that, the div or paragraph which I'm trying to highlight in a step actually overlaps the tooltip so that a portion of it is hidden.

You can see what I mean if you look at Step 3 on [this page](http://www.insurancethoughtleadership.com/index.php/inc/).

Can anyone help me solve this problem? I'm far from an expert on javascript and css, so I'm hoping someone can point out my mistakes.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer - I really appreciate it!

Frank

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the target element type, because you're using `p` tag.

Try to change the authors element type from `p` to `div` and then try again. I think this change will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Afshin. Unfortunately, that didn't work (I've left them as divs for now). When I was using the p tags, the other author elements seemed to work. What's interesting is that if I go to Step 4 and then go back to Step 3, the tooltip on Step 3 then works fine. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: @NewTester Yeah I see, if you go back to previous step, it works fine. Let me work on this issue, I'll release a patch for that. Thanks for using IntroJs and your patience.

Comment: Thanks Afshin. Happy to be using the script - it really is wonderful!

Comment: Hi Afshin - curious as to the status of the patch. I anticipate needing this to work early this coming week, so if I can't fix that problem, I'll need to look elsewhere for something similar. If you can't get to it now, that's fine - I can't expect you to meet my deadlines, especially since you graciously make the script available for free. I'm just trying to decide if I need to look for another solution. Thanks!

Comment: Afshin - just a follow-up note. I was able to find an alternative solution. Thanks for your help and sorry that in the end I wasn't able to use your script. I really do like it but I had a deadline I had to meet.